# How to sort vowels and consonants by letter that comes out first and remove "space"

Tags: javascript, arrays

if i have "google chrome great" the output vowel is "oooeeea" and consonant is "ggglchrrt".
i try this code, but the output is "test.js:26 ooeoeea"

```
test("google crhome great")
function test(e){
    var words = e.split("");
    var vowels = "AIUEOaiueo";
    var vowel = "";
    
    for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
        if(vowels.includes(e[i])){
            if(e[i] == 'a' || e[i] == 'A'){
                vowel += e[i];
            }
            if(e[i] == 'i' || e[i] == 'I'){
                vowel += e[i];
            }
            if(e[i] == 'u' || e[i] == 'U'){
                vowel += e[i];
            }
            if(e[i] == 'e' || e[i] == 'E'){
                vowel += e[i];
            }
            if(e[i] == 'o' || e[i] == 'O'){
                vowel += e[i];
            }
            
        }
    }
    console.log(vowel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order the values properly, consider putting them onto an object instead, indexed by letter. On each iteration, concatenate onto (or create) the property. At the end, take the object's values.

```js
test("google crhome great")
function test(e){
    const letters = {};
    for (const letter of e) {
      if (/[aeiou]/i.test(letter)) {
        letters[letter] = (letters[letter] || '') + letter;
      }
    }
    const vowels = Object.values(letters).join('');
    console.log(vowels);
}
```

This works because it'll iterate over the string to construct an object like

```
{
  o: 'ooo',
  e: 'eee',
  a: 'a',
}
```

and then you just need to join the values together to get your string.

Use a character set in a regular expression to keep the vowel test concise.

If you need consonants too:

```js
test("google crhome great")
function test(e){
    const vs = {};
    const cs = {};
    for (const letter of e.replaceAll(' ', '')) {
      const obj = /[aeiou]/i.test(letter) ? vs : cs;
      obj[letter] = (obj[letter] || '') + letter;
    }
    const vowels = Object.values(vs).join('');
    const consonants = Object.values(cs).join('');
    console.log(vowels, consonants);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do sth like

```js
console.log(test("google crhome great"))
function test(e){
  var words = e
    .toLowerCase() // for better compare and sort
    .split("") // convert string to array
    .filter(el => el !== " ") // remove spaces
    
  var vowel = words
    .filter(el => "aiueo" // to find vowel letters
        .split("") // to create vowel letter array
        .includes(el)
    ).sort((a,b) => 
      a.localeCompare(b) // sort from a to z. you can replace a with b and b with a for reverse sorting
    ).join('') // to convert array to string
    
  var consonant = words
    .filter(el => !"aiueo"
        .split("")
        .includes(el)
    ).sort((a,b) => 
      a.localeCompare(b)
    ).join('')
    
  return {vowel, consonant}
}
```